# unexpected flipping round of dictionaries in a list

Tags: python

I created a list of dictionaries

```
sigs = [{6,"R"},{7,"CS"},{8,"BSL"},{9,"BOAS"}]
```

but if I then check the contents I see this, note how the order of the 1st and 2nd dicts in the list have flipped round:

```
>>> sigs
[{'R', 6}, {'CS', 7}, {8, 'BSL'}, {9, 'BOAS'}]
>>>
```

can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: It is not a `dict` list,it is ``set`` which is unordered.

Comment: `{6, "R"}` is a `set`; `{6: "R"}` is a `dict`.

Comment: The order of the elements in a set display won't necessarily be preserved in the iteration order of the resulting `set` object (though the order is *fixed* and repeatable as long as no changes to the `set` instance are made).

Comment: doh!  That's embarrassing... thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your symbols are worng...

try: `sigs = [{6:"R"},{7:"CS"},{8:"BSL"},{9:"BOAS"}]`